# resilence4j+springboot2 circuit breaker is not opened

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I am trying to use resilence4j in my current spring boot2 project.I have written the following implementation classes.Even though i hit 1000 times CB is not opened.Could anyone please help finding what i was doing wrong.

**mainclass**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Controller class**

```
@RestController
public class DemoController
{
    @Autowired
    DemoService demoService;

    @GetMapping("/search")
    public String searchService()
    {
        return demoService.search();

    }

}
```

**Service class with circuit breaker:**

```
@Component(value = "demoService")
public class DemoService
{

    @CircuitBreaker(name = "demoService",fallbackMethod = "fallback")
    public String search()
    {
        throw new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "This is a remote exception");
    }

    public String fallback(Throwable throwable)
    {
        System.out.println("Entering fallback Method..........."+throwable.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Circuit Breaker Opened");
        return "Circuit Breaker Opened..";
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  application.name: demo
  jackson.serialization.indent_output: true

server:
  port: 9080

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: '*'
management.endpoint.health.show-details: always

management.health.diskspace.enabled: false
management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled: true
management.health.ratelimiters.enabled: false

info:
  name: ${spring.application.name}
  description: resilience4j demo
  environment: ${spring.profiles.active}
  version: 0.0.1

management.metrics.tags.application: ${spring.application.name}
management.metrics.distribution.percentiles-histogram.http.server.requests: true
management.metrics.distribution.percentiles-histogram.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.calls: true

#resilience4j.circuitbreaker.metrics.use_legacy_binder: true

resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  configs:
    default:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
      slidingWindowSize: 10
      minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
      automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
      waitDurationInOpenState: 5s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
  instances:
    demoService:
      baseConfig: default
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

For testing i used postman with 1000 repeated requests.

Comment: aafaik `@CircuitBreaker` doesn't work with Resilience4j. What also worries me is the fact that you specified a version tag for the `spring-boot-starter-aop` dependency, generally this indicates mixing modules from different versions of a framework. ALso `spring-boot-starter` and `spring-boot-autoconfigure` you don't need those are already implied by the other dependencies. Also make sure you followed [this](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3). Looks like you are missing the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency.

Comment: not sure what do you mean by @CircuitBreaker not work?And i tried to modify as you said but still same issue.

Comment: I assumed that it was the `@CircuitBreaker` from Spring Cloud  or Spring Retry and not the resilience4j one.Please add the imports and packages to your post as well as your full `pom.xml`.